# Drupal 7 hook_validate not called with custom form template

Tags: forms, theming

I received a pretty strange problem trying to customize custom form's template. So while form's template stay untouched (drupal core's form template was used) validation works just fine, but when I add some specific templates to my theme, validation just not working at all. Submitting a form just doesn't gives anything - MYMODULEFORM_form_validate and MYMODULEFORM_form_submit hooks are not called after form been submitted.

```
function MYTHEME_theme ()
{
    $items['MYMODULEFORM_1_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'template_1_filename',
    );
    $items['MYMODULEFORM_2_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'template_2_filename',
    );
    $items['MYMODULEFORM_3_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'template_3_filename',
    );

    return $items;
}
```

When I print out $form variable inside the template file *#validate* and *#submit* elements are present and correct. Do you have any ideas what can cause this problem I just stucked at this. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `print drupal_render_children($form);` at the bottom of the template file?

Comment: Now I have it! That You very much @Clive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Was only needed to add `print drupal_render_children($form);` at the bottom of the template file.